# Is there more elegant way to find out what's another user's default shell?

Tags: linux, shell

Is there more elegant way to find out what's another user's default shell (assuming that I have root privileges and using GNU/Linux)? I'm aware that I can get the answer by looking/parsing/greping/etc /etc/passwd, but there must be an utility (such as 'id' or 'chsh') that has a switch that prints this information to stdout.

It would be nice to run something like `id --shell username` to get the answer instantly.

**EDIT:** I see that first answers to my question can be categorized under 'parsing/looking/greping' /etc/passwd, so I'd like to emphasize that I'm aware that there are many ways to do this (shell on-liners, functions, scripts...), but that's not what I'm asking.

I'd like to know if some of standard tools that come preinstalled with most GNU/Linux distributions or tools that are part of coreutils have this feature.

Comment: No, there's no such utility - why there should be one in first place, if shell oneliner can do it reliably?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an utility just for this single purpose. Then again, we have 'groups' command that fetches similar information even if there's a way to to get the same information with shell oneliners :-)

Answer (score 5):

The `finger` command reports the shell for a user with the `-l` option

```
finger -l user
```

but you'll still need to do further processing e.g.

```
finger -l user | awk '/Shell:/ {print $4}'
```

if you just want the shell field

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any utility but adding this function to your `~/.bashrc` seems elegant enough:

```
function usershell(){
 awk -F: -v name=$1 '$1==name{print $NF}' /etc/passwd
}
```

You can then call it on a user name. For example:

```
$ usershell terdon
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Well, the end result is what I'm looking for, but it would be nice to have the same or similar output from one of coreutils tools, so that you can get the information right away when you log in to the computer/server for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`getent`](http://man.cx/getent)

```
getent passwd username | cut -d: -f7
```

Comment: Without parsing the output, with getent I get the same result when I execute "grep username /etc/passwd". So far, I like your suggestion most as it has shorter syntax than grep. If **getent** had short switches for databases, that would be exactly what I'm looking for. And before anyone mentiones bash aliases, please read my other [comment](http://superuser.com/questions/615586/is-there-more-elegant-way-to-find-out-whats-another-users-default-shell#comment763637_615594) :-)

Comment: If your system is set up with NIS or LDAP or some other centralized directory, the user may not appear in /etc/passwd.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I rarely work on systems that use LDAP, but thanks for pointing this one out.